# Add a child to a @OneToMany bidirectionnal with FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

I'm building a REST API with FOSRestBundle on my Symfony2 application.
What I want to do is to allow my POST and PUT actions, let say on a Product entity who got a @OneToMany relationship with another entity called Risk, to add/delete the children I past in JSON.

Let me give to you an example of JSON:

```
{
    "cproduct": "ASSOC000000000999",
    "risks": [
        {
            //first risk fields
        },
        {
            //second risk fields
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a simple JSON (the real one got more fields but these aren't needed here). 
So here I've my Product ID (ASSOC000000000999) and I want to update this product by adding to him 2 new risks. 
I know that normally I would have to create a Risk with the product ID separately, but for the needs of my application, I need to make only one request to the database. I want my users to be able to create a product, then add one or more risks and only then persist it into the database.

In a second time I would like them to be able to delete a child (risk) if he doesn't appear in the JSON sent with PUT action.

Here an example, let say that product “ASSOC000000000999” got a risk “RISK1”.
If I send this JSON:

```
{
    "cproduct": "ASSOC000000000999",
    "risks": [
        {
            “id”: “RISK2”,
            //other fields
        },
        {   “id”: “RISK3”,
            //other fields
        }
    ]
}
```

On persist I want RISK1 to be deleted.

How can I do that? I found nothing on the web about that, please help me. :-)

PS: Sorry for my English, this isn't my birth langage.

EDIT:
I target what my problem really is.

When I send that JSON file with HTTP PUT verb:

```
{
   "cfam": "AUTE",
   "lpronom": "My Contract",
   "riss": [{
   "cris": "AS",
   "lris": "Organization Law of 1901",
   "lrisfic": "RCAD_FICHERCA9"
   }]
}
```

Doctrine does a SELECT on RIS (my Risk table is called RIS, so the collection is $riss in my PROduct entity) where CRIS = "AS", and that's my problem. Here I want doctrine to create a RIS if the composite PK {cpro, nprover, cris} doesn't exist, and an update if it exist.

How can I do that?

(Without using Symfony form if possible).

Here my API call :

http://localhost/web/web/app_dev.php/fos/api/pros/ASSOC000000000009_1

My putProAction():

```
public function putProAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $detachedEntity = $this->reqDeserialize($request, 'Namespace\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\Pro');

    // Here I need to explode my serialized PUT parameter ID
    list($cpro, $nprover) = explode('_', $id);
    $detachedEntity->setCPRO($cpro);
    $detachedEntity->setNPROVER($nprover);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // I use merge to attache the entity to perform the persist
    $entity = $em->merge($detachedEntity);
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
    return $entity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Symfony's [Form Collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

The example listed on that page is very similar to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I'm reading it and I hope this will save me!

Comment: Ok, this is great for using only symfon2, but what I forgot to tell you is that if I need a REST API, it's because I have to use AngularJS on front side. I have to fill my object with JSON, so I need to use JMS to deserialize the JSON into a Doctrine object. This wont work with Symfony2 forms.

Comment: You should definitely still use Symfony Forms for controlling the input / output of your REST API, they will handle the validation and flow control. William Durand wrote a really article on the wider topic [here](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/), the only difference is you will need to add Collection types to deal with the sub-sets.

Comment: I've one problem with forms. If I use them, I'll have to writte a form for each entity in my application, and this isn't something I would like to have to do. But I keep this idea in mind, and I'll use it if I can't find something else! Tanks. I consider this topic closed.